# .NET setup project - Installing to a shared network drive

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation, network-programming, setup-project

I have a simple windows form application. I have created an installer for that. I am using Custom Action class (It's a separate project with custom action class and added as primary output in the setup project) to perform some operations on Commit.

Installer works fine if I install it to my local C: drive. But it fails when I try to install it to network drive mapped to my computer. Here is what I get

```
Error 1001. Error occurred while initializing the installation:
System.IO.FileNotFound Exception: could not load file or assembly file:///T:\TestFolder\Test.dll or one of it's dependencies.
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear as to who is trying to access Test.dll.

But when working with mapped drives it is better you use UNC path convention.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307420/en-us describes such a problem.

Comment: Thing is that custom action project is added as primary output and I am not specifying any path anywhere to refer this dll?